# Safely typing the keyof of a union used in a generic function

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts one of a union of objects. The return type is dependent on the keys of the object which was passed in.

```
type MyAnimals = { name: "dog", fleas: 2 } | { name: "cat" }
function GetKeys<T extends MyAnimals>(animal: T) {
  for (let k in animal) {
    const keyAsKeyOf = k as keyof T;
          // ^? const keyAsKey: keyof T
          // Why not `name` ?
  }
}
```

Why is `keyof T` not resolving to `'name' | 'fleas'`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCA7AlgWwIYBsDOUC8UA3lIuqhAFxQBEAJgPYDm1ANFAGaYTrZUBMUAL5QAPkRJlKNAMbpg1IQFgAUOwCuiacGT1EUAOIRgAaQghsAHgAqUCAA9gERLVxwkaLNgB8ACnQoMTCorAEoiFSgOegAnKB8uYCgAayhkPX8PTDDCCMioaV1sRKSzeGxTEAB5dnxkqB5ks3oaqwBuXLzOqAB6bqgAPQB+fMLi0vKzKhKQZqgrDq7I3qgAdQALEBJ6RIADUnIdqEHcwRVBIA)

Comment: Because if `T` is a subtype (for instance, `{name: "cat"}`), then `keyof T` might *not* be both `'name'` and `'fleas`'. It might be only one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

It resolves to `name`, but the IDE does not seem to show it nicely. I modified your [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCA7AlgWwIYBsDOUC8UA3lIuqhAFxQBEAJgPYDm1ANFAGaYTrZUBMUAL5QAPkRJlKNAMbpg1IQFgAUOwCuiacGT1EUAOIRgAaQghsAHgAqUCAA9gERLVxwkaLNgB8ACnQoMTCorAEoiFSgOegAnKB8uYCgAayhkPX8PTDDCCMioBOSzeGxTEAB5dnxkqB5CkHpKqwBuXMikopKzCqqAcgALeh6W5Ty64tLugh7SciHWsc7yyqnObmw5kdGtgHptqAA9AH4oaV1sRPaERapLhqgrea2oXagAdT6QEnpEgAMZiB+UEOuUEKkEQA) ;)

```js
let keyAsKeyOf = k as keyof T;
keyAsKeyOf = 'name' // works
keyAsKeyOf = 'fleas' // does not work
```

It cannot resolve to `name | fleas`, because were dealing with a union here, and only `name` is common to both options.

I agree, however, that there is a fair amount of *weirdness* surrounding the behaviour of utility types such as the `Extract` we see here ([doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)). Why is the assertion needed to be able to assign `'name'`? It would seem logical that `'name'` can be assigned to `Extract<keyof T, string>`, given that it is assignable to `keyof T`. However, according to the error hint, the narrow type `'name'` of `'name'` isn't even considered. It says that `string` cannot be assigned. Well, it ain't `string`?! [Check it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCA7AlgWwIYBsDOUC8UA3lIuqhAFxQBEAJgPYDm1ANFAGaYTrZUBMUAL5QAPkRJlKNAMbpg1IQFgAUOwCuiacGT1EUAOIRgAaQghsAHgAqUCAA9gERLVxwkaLNgB8ACnQoMTCorAEoiFSgOegAnKB8uYCgAayhkPX8PTDDCCMioBOSzeGxTEAB5dnxkgG5cyOldbETSciqAchaINtrlPMKEErMK9oALem66-uLS4YJOnr6kosHyyoI2zm5sCd6+vYB6fagAPQB+KAbEJqmVqiWQekqrSb2oQ6gAdRGQEnpEgANOv8oKcVJMCo4mlQAKIOaLoLQWe6PKBWNhNaJpRhedqdHZ9UCQKCJAiw4DwxHIp7o8lYrwLPKE6BUmwEKmohmRAp-CBQ4m4yT4vIFWiQ4B3MyPVlQDZcHhCrlGYlimFwhHACxtdBtUQygBGOrEbWkbTYWsNMpNuratDaOPW2s5+SVSRVUDJFI15utButVrEiDUqD1EGiNMxiGxVQAHE7Lth6FwAHSYJg+MUhXKCFSCIA)

Comment: I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998418/utility-type-extract-in-conjunction-with-generic-keyof-t-gives-type-that-not) that attempts to go into this more deeply, for experts like @jcalz ;)