# Utility type (Extract) in conjunction with generic (keyof T) gives type that nothing can be assigned to

Tags: typescript

Trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997722/safely-typing-the-keyof-of-a-union-used-in-a-generic-function/72997875#72997875) has left me with more questions than answers. I'll let the code speak for itself:

```js
type MyAnimals = { name: "dog", fleas: 2 } | { name: "cat" }
function GetKeys<T extends MyAnimals>(animal: T) {
  for (let k in animal) {
    let sansAssertion = k;
    sansAssertion = 'name'; // err -> whyyyyy?
    sansAssertion = 'fleas'; // err -> I get it...
    sansAssertion = 'hohoho'; // err -> yeah, that's Bullsh1t

    const thisIsConst = 'name' as const; // the type is 'name', not string, FOR SURE
    sansAssertion = thisIsConst; // err -> dafuck? Still not?

    let withAssertion = k as keyof T;
    withAssertion = 'name'; // works -> aha!
    withAssertion = 'fleas'; // err -> yeah
    withAssertion = 'hohoho'; // err -> Bullsh1t

    let letsBeExplicit: Extract<keyof T, string> = 'name'; // err -> okay, expected, by now. 
    // Can I assign ANYTHING to this??

    type SpelledOut = Extract<('name' | 'fleas') | 'name', string>
    let noGeneric: SpelledOut = 'name'; // works -> yup, okay, it's not _just_ the Extract that's broken

    type LessSpelledOut = Extract<keyof ({ name: string, fleas: number} | { name: string }), string>;
    let fromKeys: LessSpelledOut = 'name'; // works -> yeees
    fromKeys = 'fleas' // err -> yeees
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCA7AlgWwIYBsDOUC8UA3lIuqhAFxQBEAJgPYDm1ANFAGaYTrZUBMUAL5QAPkRJlKNAMbpg1IQFgAUOwCuiacGT1EUAOIRgAaQghsAHgAqUCAA9gERLVxwkaLNgB8ACnQoMTCorAEoiFSgOegAnKB8uYCgAayhkPX8PTDDCCMioBKhsf2x4bGwIaO1dfGSAblzIosQSsoqqvQIAclJyTtqoAHoB22jYgFovKAB3AAsQefmAfgbC4tLyyp0OqE7Obmw+weGK8cmASShGI1TgADp7laaWjfaazpn6D4-DoZHTqBA3BmbGAMzknVwACE1JgcDMAIzAFQraS6bCJUHIbBnbAAYTRiS6PQgnSgPCgqOawH6v1B0FAkFSuG6kk6bEQ9ES6OiaUYbAAYgB5ABKUAAygBVYUAUUea1am2qBEx2LxBJpx1GUAmUFo6HU0iSi3F2lhJE5y2UKwKU2QoPWbS2NRS5KSZno7CgVnqyjy0ztMwdiu2LN6GumMSSuB16DBAEIVrb7QrXl09jwfpr-oDY4mA0HUzsvp96Jm-trJtDYdgEUirb68gUEthIRBpXYwJhkNI7VR28BougtBY3SAPV62NzeZMiazwycK1B6El0CA2PZIFoILQ2AAjEDmqa3KC4-xQC48bDIRh6eAAOQAmlYABJnO-6KDAeifmZYxaWlYGWgMVIFhbdBTUQkoH7Qdhx8UMSVEHZ0wOMIxAQtlCgHadrWuDlDEQCpuyoECIDA2gIKgjDwymSNo0mEA1DANhl1XNg7Qhc1EgAfQAKzUdFuJ-aAYKHDEwWATjd2iZcnGRBtIiAqAABkIDKUjyMompROHUdxx8YhiSoKdED5DguB4KhEDUVBdwqYQxEMyRjOw0yhBCSdXMYLwfT9Ap2Bk1BTHMKhVPU0CuAoyC3mJMtaOiKNF0BCA1JWAL6CCsxcDTCyDiOcsdWS1KG0EFRBCAA)

In case my question isn't clear by now: TypeScript is clearly able to understand the `keyof T` type and acts as expected. `keyof T` contains a union of a bunch of different strings (only one, in this case). It would be *expected*, that `Extract<ABunchOfStrings, string> === ABunchOfStrings`, yet it is not **if** `ABunchOfStrings` comes from a generic type `keyof T`. Whyyyyy?

Answer (score 1):

That you can't assign anything to `Extract<keyof T, string>` was once considered a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24560). But recently this issue was labeled as a *"design limitation*" so it will probably never get fixed.

So the behavior you are seeing is pretty much expected. My guess is that TypeScript is not trying to resolve the expression `Extract<keyof T, string>` and just leaves it as is which leads to an error at assignment.

Comment: Yeah, the evaluation of distributive conditional types (like `Extract`) that depend on generic type parameters (like `T`) is deferred, so such types are opaque to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the types !

You get `let k: Extract<keyof T, string>`.

We know that `keyof T = 'name' (but could also be` fleas`if narrowed) and`type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never`

So `Extract<keyof T, string>` equals to `T` since your keys are strings.

But the thing is, you don't really now what `T` is outside having **at least** `{name: string} | {name: string, fleas: number`.

So the compiler will throw you a TS2322 error if you do something like this : `const sansAssertion: T = { name: 'dog' };`

```
Type '{ name: "dog"; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ name: "dog"; }'
```

Anyway it's a **bad** thing to modify someting you access in a for loop.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, there a bunch of typos that make it difficult to fully follow your reasoning